# Import matplotlib.pyplot in python 2.7

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Anaconda (python 2.7) spyder interface. I am new in python. I want to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" but it says "No module named matplotlib.pyplot". I already installed matplotlib from command line using "conda install matplotlib" ! I don't know how it works !

Comment: Anaconda already comes with `matplotlib`. You didn't need to use `conda install matplotlib`. Either way, check your spelling and ensure the environment is set properly.

Comment: In spyder, `import sys` and `print sys.path` to see what your system path is. Then, try and locate your matplotlib installation directory, and see if the parent directory of the matplotlib directory is included in `sys.path`. Best to [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33728443/edit) your question with both `sys.path` and the matplotlib installation directory, for clarity.